# which Keras accuracy metric for multiclass classification

Tags: keras, image-classification, accuracy

I am training a CNN for multiclass image classification into 4 images , what accuracy metric should i use from Keras. My labels are not one hot encoded as I am trying to predict probability of different images.

Comment: What do you mean that you have not one-hot encoded the labels because you want to predict the probabilities? Do you mean the outputs are probabilities instead of categories?

Comment: Yeah , the I want the outputs to be probabilities not a single class , I am working on an emotion classifier whose output I later want to feed to a recommendation algo , as a project , so based on the probabilities of the output emotions , I want to be able to suggest music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiclass classification you can simply use a **categorical cross entropy loss** function. Depending on **whether or not** the values are **one-hot encoded** you would have to use either the **sparse categorical cross entropy loss** or the **normal categorical cross entropy loss**.

Another option is **f1_score** which is a combination of **precision_score** and **recall_score**. Below is an implementation in **keras** which you can use:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def f1(y_true, y_pred):    
    def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
        TP = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        Positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        
        recall = TP / (Positives+K.epsilon())    
        return recall 
    
    
    def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
        TP = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        Pred_Positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    
        precision = TP / (Pred_Positives+K.epsilon())
        return precision 
    
    precision, recall = precision_m(y_true, y_pred), recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are predicting probabilities for each class, you can use the "categorical_crossentropy" loss function in Keras and set the "softmax" activation function on the output layer of your CNN.

Since your labels are not one-hot encoded, you can use the "sparse_categorical_accuracy" metric in Keras to evaluate the accuracy of your model. This metric will compare the predicted class probabilities to the actual class labels.

Here is an example code snippet:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    # add your CNN layers here
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax') # output layer with 4 classes and softmax activation
])
```

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

Note that even though your labels are not one-hot encoded, Keras will automatically convert them to one-hot encoded format internally when using the "categorical_crossentropy" loss function.